# Android getApplicationContext Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to save a location via application context, so I did the following :

myApp Class :

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

```
public class myApp extends Application {

  private GeoPoint Tunis = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.827589),microdegrees(10.171165));
  private GeoPoint myLocation=Tunis;

  public GeoPoint getMyLocation(){
    return myLocation;
  }
  public void setMyLocation(GeoPoint s){
    myLocation = s;
  }
  private int microdegrees(double value){
   return (int)(value*1000000);
  }

}
```

My manifest :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".myApp">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

and in my main activity I did this :

```
myApp appState = ((myApp)getApplicationContext());
```

and this causes a NullPointerException when I launch the application :( can you please tell me why this exception occurs ? I thought that in myApp class I initialized MyLocation to an existing GeoPoint ?

Thanks,

Comment: Without more source code and a full stack trace, nobody can help you much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the disturb, I solved this by:
1- Adding constructor to myApp :

```
public class myApp extends Application {

  public GeoPoint Tunis = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.827589),microdegrees(10.171165));
  public GeoPoint myLocation;

  public myApp(){
      super();
      myLocation=Tunis;
  }
  public GeoPoint getMyLocation(){
    return myLocation;
  }
  public void setMyLocation(GeoPoint s){
    myLocation = s;
  }
  private int microdegrees(double value){
      return (int)(value*1000000);
  }
}
```

2- Declaring the following in my Main activity in onCreate void

```
appState = ((myApp)getApplicationContext());
```

like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      GeoPoint Tunis = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(36.827589),microdegrees(10.171165));
      MyMap=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.MyGMap);
      MyMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      MyController=MyMap.getController();
      MyController.setZoom(12);
      MyController.setCenter(Tunis);
      appState = ((myApp)getApplicationContext());
```

thanks

Comment: To be more precise: the problem is that you can't access getApplicationContext() before the Activity is created, ie before onCreate has been called.